# dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I was trying to configure hadoop with one name node and four data nodes.  I was able to successfully configure the name node and job tracker on one machine and bring it up.

But on my machine where the data node is to be configured I did the following:

- I unzipped the `hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.1.2.tar.gz` and `mr1-2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.1.2.tar.gz` into a folder and set up the configuration with master and slave.
- In the `master` file I had set up the ip address of machine that was configured to be the name node.
- In the slave machine I set up the ip address of my machine where I had unzipped the tar balls.

When I try to start the data node with the command

```
hdfs datanode
```

I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
```

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 13):

The name of the `masters` file is misleading. It should contain the address of the SecondaryNameNode and is read by the NameNode itself. DataNodes do not have anything to do with the `masters` file. You need to configure `fs.default.name` on `core-site.xml` configuration file.

The error you see is also [misleading](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-2595) and points you to the wrong configuration parameter.

Answer (score 6):

These steps solved the problem for me :

1. export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop"
2. echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR
3. hdfs namenode -format
4. hdfs getconf -namenodes
5. start-dfs.sh

Then, Hadoop can properly started.

Comment: Had to create `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` as Hadoop was not reading the configurations from `core-site.xml`. I created `HADOOP_HOME/conf/hadoop-env.sh` and added required variables (HADOOP_CONF_DIR, HADOOP_HDFS_HOME etc.) in `hadoop-env.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the rpc-address in hdfs-site.xml for the name node will work like this

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address</name>
<value>dnsname:port</value>
</property>
```

also in core-site add the property

`<property>
      <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
      <value>dnsname:port</value>
</property>`

Comment: This answer helped me out. Thanks!