# Hadoop : NameNode , DataNode and SecondaryNameNode are not running

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I'm trying to install Hadoop 2.2.0 on a Single Node Cluster on my computer using this tutorial http://codesfusion.blogspot.gr/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1 . I follow every instruction I see, step-by-step but I have the same problem every time. NameNode , DataNode and SecondaryNameNode not running. The message I see when I enter start-dfs.sh , start-yarn.sh and jps is :

```
hduser@victor-OEM:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ start-dfs.sh
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-victor-OEM.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-victor-OEM.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
The authenticity of host '0.0.0.0 (0.0.0.0)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 62:ec:99:e3:ce:2d:f8:79:1f:f8:9a:2a:25:9d:17:95.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
0.0.0.0: Warning: Permanently added '0.0.0.0' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-victor-OEM.out
hduser@victor-OEM:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-victor-OEM.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-victor-OEM.out
hduser@victor-OEM:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
10684 NodeManager
10745 Jps
10455 ResourceManager
```

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531590/dfs-namenode-servicerpc-address-or-dfs-namenode-rpc-address-is-not-configured ?

Comment: I've read it , but it did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain versions of the [codefusion tutorial](http://codesfusion.blogspot.gr/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html) (such as [this one](http://codesfusion.blogspot.com/2013/10/setup-hadoop-2x-220-on-ubuntu.html?m=1)) omit the xml tags within code blocks such that:

```
#add this to foo.txt   
<bizz>bar</bizz>
```

became:

```
#add this to foo.txt
bar
```

Including the xml tags in the configuration resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "missing html tags". How could a XML file contain html tags anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this link:[Leraning hadoop](http://learninghadoopblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/hadoop-0-23-9-single-node-setup-on-ubuntu-13-04/).  It is for 0.23.9 but also works for 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Disable IPv6 in the hadoop-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I solved it by disabling firewalls.

Just use this command

```
sudo ufw disbale
```

Answer (score -5):

I tried below steps:

1. **ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""**
2. **cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys**

After that, opening a new terminal and start the Hadoop cluster which solves my problem.