# Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera-cdh

I am getting this error when I try and boot up a DataNode. From what I have read, the RPC paramters are only used for a HA configuration, which I am not setting up (I think).

```
2014-05-18 18:05:00,589 INFO  [main] impl.MetricsSystemImpl (MetricsSystemImpl.java:shutdown(572)) - DataNode metrics system shutdown complete.
2014-05-18 18:05:00,589 INFO  [main] datanode.DataNode (DataNode.java:shutdown(1313)) -     Shutdown complete.
2014-05-18 18:05:00,614 FATAL [main] datanode.DataNode (DataNode.java:secureMain(1989)) - Exception in secureMain
java.io.IOException: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSUtil.getNNServiceRpcAddresses(DFSUtil.java:840)
at   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolManager.refreshNamenodes(BlockPoolManager.java:151)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:745)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:278)
```

My files look like:

[root@datanode1 conf.cluster]# cat core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>

<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

## cat hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
<property>
 <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
 <value>/hdfs/data</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>dfs.permissions.superusergroup</name>
 <value>hadoop</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I am using the latest CDH5 distro.

```
Installed Packages
Name        : hadoop-hdfs-datanode
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 2.3.0+cdh5.0.1+567
Release     : 1.cdh5.0.1.p0.46.el6
```

Any helpful advice on how to get past this?

EDIT: Just use Cloudera manager.

Comment: Is [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531590/dfs-namenode-servicerpc-address-or-dfs-namenode-rpc-address-is-not-configured) useful?

Answer (score 24):

I too was facing the same issue and finally found that there was a space in fs.default.name value. truncating the space fixed the issue. The above core-site.xml doesn't seem to have space so the issue may be different from what i had. my 2 cents

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.
Removing spaces between properties did solve my problem.
I was following the digital ocean guide.

Comment: Had the same issue, (caused by copying the code from [the tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hadoop/hadoop_enviornment_setup.htm) without cleaning up)

Comment: I had a similar issue. Rather than a space, I simply had invalid information in the same place for fs.default.name. Everything worked fine after I fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

These steps solved the problem for me:

- `export HADOOP_CONF_DIR = $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop`
- `echo $HADOOP_CONF_DIR`
- `hdfs namenode -format`
- `hdfs getconf -namenodes`
- `./start-dfs.sh`

Answer (score 1):

check the core-site.xml under $HADOOP_INSTALL/etc/hadoop dir. Verify that the property fs.default.name is configured correctly

Answer (score 1):

Obviously,your core-site.xml has configure error.

```
<property>
 <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
 <value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>
</property>
```

Your `<name>fs.defaultFS</name>` setting as `<value>hdfs://namenode:8020</value>`,but your machine **hostname** is `datanode1`.So you just need change `namenode` to `datanode1` will be OK.

Comment: this answer and Hamdi Charef's answer together were my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I found a resolution by checking the environment on the Data Node:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /etc/hadoop/conf hadoop-conf /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster 50
$ sudo update-alternatives --set hadoop-conf /etc/hadoop/conf.my_cluster
```

Make sure that the alternatives are set correctly on the Data Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I have wrongly set HADOOP_CONF_DIR to an other Hadoop installation.

Add to hadoop-env.sh:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring the full host name in core-site.xml, masters and slaves solved the issue for me.

Old: **node1** (failed)

New: **node1.krish.com** (Succeed)

Answer (score 0):

creating dfs.name.dir and dfs.data.dir directories and configuring full hostname in core-site.xml, masters & slaves is solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

In my situation, I fixed by change /etc/hosts config to lower case.

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem mainly arises is there is a space in the value or name of the property in any one of the following files- 
core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-site.xml

just make sure you did not put any spaces or (changed the line) in between the opening and closing name and value tags.

Code:

```
 <property> 
<name>dfs.name.dir</name> <value>file:///home/hadoop/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value> 
<final>true</final> 
</property>
```

Comment: Give some example please

Comment: you should add in your answer so that all can get it. i have done it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, formatting HDFS solved my issue. **Don't format HDFS if you have important meta data.**
Command for formatting HDFS: `hdfs namenode -format`

[When namenode was not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWfQi.png)
[image: When namenode was not working]

[After formatting HDFS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x6uy.png)
[image: After formatting HDFS]

Answer (score 0):

Check your '*/etc/hosts*' file:

 There must be a line like below: (if not, so add that) 

`namenode   127.0.0.1`


Replace 127.0.01 with your *namenode* IP.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in hadoop-env.cmd

```
set HADOOP_HOME_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware, lately answering this.

Should check following to fix :

1. Master is able to ping slave by name and vice-versa; If you have used host names in configuration instead of ip address. if not able to ping should review /etc/hosts on both master and slave.. add entries of all nodes in all nodes.
2. After all configuration changes are done on master, execute following on master. * change <USER_> and <SLAVE_NODE> to actual values.

`scp $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/* <USER_>@<SLAVE_NODE>:$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/`