# Hadoop fs -ls outputs current working directory's files rather than hdfs volume's files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2

Have set up a single pseudo-distributed node (localhost) with Hadoop 2.8.2 on OpenSuse Tumbleweed 20170703. Java version is 1.8.0_151. Generally, it seems to be set up correctly. I can format `namenode` with no errors etc.

However, when I try `hadoop fs -ls`, files/dirs from the current working directory are returned rather than the expected behaviour of returning the `hdfs` volume files (which should be nothing at the moment).

Was originally following [this guide for CentOS](https://www.tecmint.com/install-configure-apache-hadoop-centos-7) (making changes as required) and the [Apache Hadoop guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html#YARN_on_Single_Node).

I'm assuming that it's a config issue, but I can't see why it would be. I've played around with `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` as per below with no luck.

`/opt/hadoop-hdfs-volume/` exists and is assigned to user `hadoop` in user group `hadoop`. As is the `/opt/hadoop/` directory (for bin stuff).

---

**EDIT:**

`/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/dfs/name` is where the `hdfs namenode -format` command runs. `/tmp/` also seems to hold my user (`/tmp/hadoop-dijksterhuis`) and the `hadoop` user directories.

This seems odd to me considering the `*-site.xml` config files below.

Have tried restarting the `dfs` and `yarn` services with the `.sh` scripts in the `hadoop/sbin/` directory. Have also rebooted. No luck!

---

core-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
        <value>/opt/hadoop-hdfs-volume/${user.name}</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/data</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>${hadoop.tmp.dir}/dfs/name</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Anyone have any ideas? I can provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to hack a fix via [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35757570/5945794):

Add `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/opt/hadoop/etc/hadoop` to the `hadoop` user's `.bashrc`.

This has the effect of overriding the value in `etc/hadoop-env.sh`, which keeps pointing the namenode to the default `tmp/hadoop-${user-name}` directory.

`source .bashrc` et voila! Problem fixed.