# Hadoop 2.7.3: Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured

Tags: hadoop

I have three machines centOS 7 where I want to deploy hadoop 2.7.3.

I got the following error:

```
[root@hadoop-master hadoop]# sbin/start-dfs.sh
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
cat: /opt/hadoop/hadoop/slaves: No file ou folder found
sed: -e expression n°1, caracter 6: option unknown pour `s'
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
```

I checked many website but it didn't not solve my problem. Does anyone have an idea ?

For information, here are my mxl files:

**Core-site.xml for master and slave**

```
<configuration>
  <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml for master**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml for slave**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
        <value>2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource.tracker.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:8025</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>hadoop-master:8050</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389376/hadoop-datanode-startup-fail-incorrect-configuration-namenode-address-dfs-nam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14531590/dfs-namenode-servicerpc-address-or-dfs-namenode-rpc-address-is-not-configured

Comment: check this links. It may helped you

Comment: any workaround guys ?